# stored procedure of contact us table in asp.net does not execute correctly

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

```
ALTER PROC SP_Contact_Msg
--@Reg_id as int, 
@Email as varchar(50), 
@txtName as varchar(50),
@txtBody as varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Reg_Id AS INT

    SET @Reg_Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Reg_Id FROM reg WHERE Email = @Email)

    IF @Reg_id != NULL 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO Contact ( Reg_id, Email, txtName, txtBody, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn, IsActive) 
        values (@Reg_id, @Email, @txtName, @txtBody, GETDATE(), 1, NULL, NULL, 1) 
    END

    IF @Reg_id = NULL  
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO Contact (Reg_id, Email, txtName, txtBody, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn, IsActive) 
        VALUES (null, @Email, @txtName, @txtBody, GETDATE(), 1, NULL, NULL, 1) 
    END
END
```

please help me this procedure does not work correctly when i give email of register(reg) user email its not show the (reg_id) just show null, its only execute only else condition

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Also, it is nothing to do with asp.net; tag to appropriate technology;

Comment: what parameters are commented? only @Reg_id or all of them? It's not very clear due to formatting

Comment: The `!= NULL` is probably part of the problem. Should be `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: just @Reg_id  is commented

Comment: thank you Kidiskidvogingogin its working now :)

Comment: Expanding on @Kidiskidvogingogin comment -- the last IF should be `IS NULL` not `= NULL` also.

Comment: @SundasAli Happy to help. You may find [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/how-to-get-nulls-horribly-wrong-in-sql-server/) helpful. There's a section in there about using operators with `NULL`s

Comment: @Kidiskidvogingogin please guide me about Input and output parameters for stored procedures,

Answer (score 0):

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]    I think this code would help you.

```
 create table Reg(Reg_id int identity(1,1), Email varchar(100))
         insert into Reg values('pavan@gmail.com')

      create table Contact(Reg_id int, Email varchar(50), txtName varchar(100), txtBody varchar(100), CreatedOn datetime, CreatedBy varchar(30), UpdatedBy varchar(30), UpdatedOn datetime, IsActive int)

    Create PROC SP_Contact_Msg
    (
    --@Reg_id as int, 
    @Email as varchar(50), 
    @txtName as varchar(50),
    @txtBody as varchar(50) 
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @Reg_Id AS INT

        SET @Reg_Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Reg_Id FROM reg WHERE Email = @Email)

        IF (@Reg_id is not NULL )
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO Contact ( Reg_id, Email, txtName, txtBody, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn, IsActive) 
            values (@Reg_id, @Email, @txtName, @txtBody, GETDATE(),'NULL', 'NULL', GETDATE(), 1) 
        END

        else   
        BEGIN 
            INSERT INTO Contact (Reg_id, Email, txtName, txtBody, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn, IsActive) 
            VALUES (null, @Email, @txtName, @txtBody, GETDATE(),'NULL' , 'NULL', GETDATE(), 1) 
        END
    END
```